# Meta tag not functioning on one page but works on all the others?

Tags: html, css, coldfusion

This is the meta tag:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

It works on all pages, except 1.

The pages are being rendered with coldfusion includes `<cfinclude>` and is setup in a directory structure similar to MVC. The page that the tag is broken on has it's own controller (but only shows one page), but that controller is identical to the other's. I'm not sure what could be causing this.

The pages are also setup in modular design, where each function of the page is imported in chunks. Each page has it's own unique modules, so the problem is there in one of those chunks......... I just don't know what that problem could possibly be. I've been combing over the modules for the past few days and just can't find it.

What could possibly be causing this meta tag to not work? There is too much code paste here, so I'm hoping for an answer that can lead me in a direction to look for the solution. I don't believe it has anything to do with Coldfusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was wrong. The issue does in fact stem from Coldfusion.

Since I did not create the page that was having the issue, I overlooked an important part. The person who created it was using the cfform input tags with verification. The caused Coldfusion to insert this into the rendered page at the end of the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
    _CF_checkeditUserInfo = function(_CF_this)
    {
       //reset on submit
       _CF_error_exists = false;
       _CF_error_messages = new Array();
       _CF_error_fields = new Object();
       _CF_FirstErrorField = null;


       //display error messages and return success
       if( _CF_error_exists )
       {
           if( _CF_error_messages.length > 0 )
           {
               // show alert() message
               _CF_onErrorAlert(_CF_error_messages);
               // set focus to first form error, if the field supports js focus().
               if( _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].type == "text" )
               { _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].focus(); }

           }
        return false;
       }else {
           return true;
       }
   }
//-->
</script>
```

Now I'm not entirely sure what this is doing to cause the meta tag to break, but when I remove the module that causes this script to be generated, the issue is fixed. When that is removed text compare shows that the rendered headers in both pages have 0 differences.

I completely fixed my specific issue by [setting the WebConfig in IIS itself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2008/09/05/configuring-iis-to-work-around-webpage-display-issues-caused-by-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

- First, as drezabek stated, inspect the *resulting* HTML. IE is especially picky about that specific meta header. From my experience the `IE=EDGE` header must be the very first header on the entire page and must be the first item at the top of your `<head>` Check your HTML, is that the case?
- Second, Coldfusion is notoriously troublesome about extra whitespace. If there is whitespace above your doctype, or possibly the header in question it could cause it to malfunction. When in doubt always use `output='false'` on all of your functions, even your `cfscript` functions. In addition, even some native CF methods add whitespace. For example serialize an ORM object, `SerializeJSON(EntityLoad('blah'))`, and you'll see it throws in some whitespace. Joy.

Comment: The HTML is the same on both pages when I view source and if it's a whitespace issue, it would be a whitespace issue on all the pages because they all have the exact same header code.

Comment: Could you share some of the HTML? Throw it in a jsfiddle or gist if you don't have a public webserver.

Comment: I do not have a public webserver and unfortunately, the information is somewhat sensitive. I will post the headers in the original question, hopefully that will help.

Comment: While going through and trying to add it to the question, I found the issue. I'm going to give you the +50 (in 8hrs due to timer on SO) and post the answer myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer must lie within the HTML. View the source for a page that works, and the one that doesn't, and try looking for a difference that could cause the problem. If you can't find it, maybe post the source here?

The HTML really is the key. After you have that, finding the function that is causing the bad HTML should be easy.